# Docker - `top` like real time metrics in command line

Tags: docker, monitoring

When running Docker containers, I'd like to get real time metrics reports of all my running containers?

I'd like to see the memory, cpu and network usage in real time, like the `top` command on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice tool to help you with this requirement.

**Ctop** ([github link](https://github.com/bcicen/ctop)). Top-like interface for container metrics. It's works really well, and is easy to use.

Note - you can also use `docker stats`, but it has fewer options and a simpler display.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have some tools from docker to start with

docker stats

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/

docker top

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/top/

keep in mind that you can use various `ps options` with `docker top`

An example

`$ docker top b753f4832fb -o pid,cmd`

will show something like

`PID                 CMD
6103                /usr/bin/vi`

Comment: `docker top` is great, but (AFAIK) is restricted to a single container.